# Distributing Eclipse plugin with dependencies

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I recently wrote an Eclipse plugin, and I'm trying to get some coworkers to install it for testing.

As far as I can tell, dropping the `.jar` into the `dropins` folder in Eclipse is supposed to install it, but it seems to not be working on any installation of Eclipse but the one I developed on. This seems to be a problem with the dependencies not being installed.

I thought that the `dropins` folder was supposed to automatically calculate and install dependencies, but perhaps I'm wrong. If so, how can I distribute it without having everybody install each dependency separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend against using the dropins folder.  It is unreliable as you have seen.  Instead, I'd recommend that you export your plugin as an update site.

So:

2. Create a feature for your plugin.  This is a lot simpler than it sounds.  See Lars Vogel's tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html
3. File -> Export... -> Deployable Features.
4. In the options, section, select "Package as individual jar files..." (see screenshot) [image]
5. Tweak other things as required
6. Finish

Now, you have an update site that you can zip up, or put on a web server somewhere.  Your colleagues can add that update site just like any other.  To install, make sure that they also have all of the dependencies available from other update sites and that they have "Contact all update sites..." checked.

The nice thing about this is that if you place your plugins on a web server somewhere, and you replace it with a new versions, people will be able to update transparently.

Comment: This looks like a solution, but I'm getting stuck on some of the specific details. I assume I'm using Dependencies for dependencies, but do I need to add any included features? Additionally, when I export it I get a .jar - what's the right way to publish this?

Comment: To keep things simple, you probably don't want to use any included feature.  Properly declared plugin dependencies should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Each exported plugin and feature will have its own jar file, in the eclipse/plugins and eclipse/features directories respectively.  It could be that you are exporting as an archive file.  In this case, you should be able to simply unzip your update site and place it on a web server.

Comment: More info: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_features.htm